# MSVCP120.dll and MSVCR120.dll are missing

Tags: windows-10, visual-c++

I don't know how that happened. I was installing Battlefield 1 and now I can't even start Origin. I am getting "*MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer*" (same for MSVCR120.dll).

I have installed [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840) for x86 and x64 but I'm still getting this message.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> I am getting "MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer"
>
> What am I missing?

You need to install the correct version of the Visual C++ Redistributable

**[Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587)**, installs, MSVCP140.dll  and MSVCR140.dll.

**Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable**, installs, MSVCP120.dll  and MSVCR120.dll.

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

### In Summary:

- v170 - Belongs to Visual Studio 2022
- v160 - Belongs to Visual Studio 2019
- v150 - Belongs to Visual Studio 2017
- v140 - Belongs to Visual Studio 2015
- v120 - Belongs to Visual Studio 2013
- v110 - Belongs to Visual Studio 2012
- v100 - Belong to Visual Studio 2010
- v90 - Belongs to Visual Studio 2008
- v80 - Belongs to Visual Studio 2005

Additional Downloads:

- [Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @displayname - If an installation for a game does not install the C++ Redistributable, then that is a problem you seek to resolve with the publisher of the game.  I don't answer questions in the comment section.  Since your question about Origin doesn't have anything to do with my answer I have flagged it as "It's no longer needed."  I politely request the comment section only be used as feedback to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen answers on other sites indicating installation of C++ 2013 and 2015 have helped fix this, and another was to uninstall/reinstall Origin but do not choose the beta when reinstalling Origin:

[C++ 2013 Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

[C++ 2015 Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)