# Starting Snort gives an Error on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, snort

I installed Snort on Windows 10, but when I try to start it with *snort -V* it gives back an Error *could not find VCRUNTIME140.dll* .

I tried to reinstall/repair the Programm Snort, but it gives the same Error.
Maybe debugging it could be an idea ?

What could be the cause and how to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Does it help to go to:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads and download/install the x86 and x64 versions under the "Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" heading?

Comment: I will try, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSVCP120.dll and MSVCR120.dll are missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1163409/msvcp120-dll-and-msvcr120-dll-are-missing)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to install both 32/64bit for 140dll .

Comment: @Ramhound.. that might have helped except he is looking for v14, not v12.  Did I miss something here?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Yes; I updated my answer to the duplicate, it now contains a link to both.  I have other duplicate candidates (around 5)

Comment: This article might help you, please kindly check. [How to Fix the “VCRUNTIME140.dll Is Missing” Error on Windows 10](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-fix-the-vcruntime140dll-is-missing-error-on-windows-10)

Comment: Thank you all, now it starts without error. I installed this file vc_redist.x64.exe along with snort 64bit.