# How to find direct download links to older specific version of Visual C++ redistributable 2022?

Tags: download, visual-c++, redistributable, visual-studio-2022

Let's say I want to download the 2022 Visual C++ redistributable x86 version 14.30.30708.0 (this is not the lastest version). Where can I download this older specific version on a Microsoft website?

I know the lastest version can be downloaded here: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe But I don't want the lastest version, I want an older specific version.

I found this answer in which some direct download links are present, but I am not sure how those links have been found, and how to find other versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34209692

How can those direct download links can be found?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2005-vc-80-sp1-no-longer-supported

Comment: [Why](https://superuser.com/questions/1163409/msvcp120-dll-and-msvcr120-dll-are-missing/1163505#1163505) are you trying to do this?  The SO question does not list a single version of the 2022. You mention VC++ 2022 but the SO does not list it.  So that makes me wonder if your trying to install multiple versions of the VC++ or multiple versions of a specific version of the VC++ (i.e. v170).  So understanding what you are trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: I need it for a Wix bundle installer. If I use the link to the lastest version, the Wix installer breaks each time there is an update of the VC++ redist because the payload changes.

Comment: I found interesting info here: https://gist.github.com/nathancorvussolis/6852ba282647aeb0c5c00e742e28eb48?permalink_comment_id=3164669#gistcomment-3164669 In this page, there is a link to version 14.30.30704. But I want to learn how to find those links. I know that I can embed offline VC++ redist into Wix bundle, but I have other issue with this technique, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470159/why-azure-build-agent-doesnt-include-executable-in-wix-bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find an official link to the specific version I wanted, but thanks to [Baldruk](https://renderdoc.org/vcredist_symbols/) (who gave me the hint on what to do) and [this page](https://winblog.it.umn.edu/2018/05/19/getting-redirected-uris-in-powershell/), I am now able to get the redirected url of the lastest VC++ redist 2015-2022 by using this powershell line:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head -Uri "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe").BaseResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
```

This returns https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/144a5711-f076-44fa-bf55-f7e0121eb30c/B7AE307237F869E09F7413691A2CD1944357B5CEE28049C0A0D3430B47BB3EDC/VC_redist.x86.exe
which is the link to "Microsofot Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x86) - 14.31.31103".

But there is [no guarantee](https://gist.github.com/nathancorvussolis/6852ba282647aeb0c5c00e742e28eb48?permalink_comment_id=3224505#gistcomment-3224505) that this url won't break, so instead of downloading the VC++ redist with my installer, I might embed the offline redist in my [Wix bundle installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470159/why-azure-build-agent-doesnt-include-executable-in-wix-bundle).

Answer (score 4):

Researching for the exactly same problem, I've stumbled upon this wonderful document:
https://github.com/abbodi1406/vcredist/blob/master/source_links/README.md

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks for sharing.