# Why am I getting this “Loading script failed (access denied).” error?

Tags: windows-11

I keep on getting this message and I don't know what I should do to solve this issue. I have also tried installing `msvcp140_2.dll` manually but I see no improvement in my problem. This error pops up whenever I open my system or after 1-2 minutes if I try to close it manually.

The error message.

> [image: The error message.]

My system specificaton.

> [image: My system specificaton.]

And these are the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable that I have.

> [image: And these are the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable that I have.]

Another error I get if I try to move msvcp140_2.dll away from the Windows folder

> [image: Another error I get if I try to move msvcp140_2.dll away from the windows folder.]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot showing that [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022) is installed on your system? Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1163409/msvcp120-dll-and-msvcr120-dll-are-missing/1163505#1163505)

Comment: Welcome to the community. Can you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767586/edit) your question to add a bit more details? What exactly are you doing and how do you do it when this error pops up? DLL files aren't scripts, and access to Win folder is protected, so... As for future reference, when adding the version of OS or application, it's a good idea to add the exact version number instead of "Latest". A year from now "latest" is something completely different and advice you get now might not apply anymore :-)

Comment: Hi, @Ramhound I have updated my question. I hope this helps.

Comment: @AayushYash - The application that requires Microsoft C++ 2015 Redistributable is a 32-bit or 64-bit application? When was the application published?  While what you have is supposed to be binary compatible with the what the application requires, you might have found an edge case, where it actually will not work thus requiring you to install Microsoft C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3.  The added difficulty is is that version of the Microsoft C++ 2015 Redistributable compatible with Windows 11.

Comment: I don't know which application requires 2015 Redistributable, as I'm facing this problem after the 5th of Feb and before that, I haven't installed anything on my system. As far as I can remember, the only thing that I have done is update my windows (which windows 11 automatically does in the background). And I didn't face any issues till the 7th. Another thing that I have noticed is if I try to move msvcp140_2 away from the windows folder, I get a new type of error (updated the original question). Even after uninstalling/reinstalling 2015 Redistributable, I get the same message.

Comment: That sounds like malware if you don't know which application it is. Have you disabled all AutoRuns entries to see if the behavior continues to happen? The file that is required is legitimate; the fact it cannot be found is a different problem; likewise, the fact you have no idea which application is being run that requires the file is concerning [msvcp140-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000672/what-are-the-msvcp140-1-dll-and-msvcp140-2-dll-files-in-the-microsoft-c-runtime)